# How do I compare to a custom property list?

Tags: python, custom-properties

I created a custom property group with a list of strings (populated with the name of image textures). How do I compare the list of textures in my scene to this custom property list?

```
import bpy

class CustomPropertiesGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
  customString: bpy.props.StringProperty()

bpy.utils.register_class(CustomPropertiesGroup)

bpy.types.Scene.customLists = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=CustomPropertiesGroup) 

bpy.context.scene.customLists.clear()

# Filling up the custom list with the texture names 
for m in bpy.data.images:
    if len(m.filepath) != 0:
        newCustomItem = bpy.context.scene.customLists.add()
        newCustomItem.customString = m.name
```

Later in the code I  would like to modify the texture path of those textures which are on my list but I don't know how to iterate over the scene textures and over the custom list at the same time to see if there is a match.
This code below doesn't work as it only has the last item in the custom list and therefore it's only true for that last item:

```
for m in bpy.data.images:
    if m.name in customPropertyGroup.customString:
        print("Something...")
```

How can I compare the actual **m.name** to all of the items in the custom list?

Comment: `if m.name in [pg.customString for pg in bpy.context.scene.customLists]:` ? It's called a list comprehension if you want to look it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the question with the super answer from Gorgious:

```
for m in bpy.data.images:
    if m.name in [pg.customString for pg in bpy.context.scene.customLists]:
        print("Something...")
```

works perfectly. (Never heard of *list comprehension* but now I know. Thanks.)